# Microsoft Word Mac Can't Add Exclude Dictionary

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, dictionary

I'm trying to add an exclusion dictionary to Mac Word 2016. After going to Word | Preferences |Spelling and Proofing, Dictionaries, I click Add. The open file dialog shows an Options button with three choices, one being for Exclude dictionaries

However, none of the files I want to select are enabled. I can change the option to All Files, and while they become active and can be selected, the dictionary seems to be ignored afterward. I quit Word, and restart but none of the words get marked.

Is this procedure correct? Are there any known bugs with the Mac Word exclusion dictionaries?

Comment: Here is the Word for Windows procedure. It may help. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/ExcludeWordFromDic.htm

Comment: I saw that, thanks. However, it's for the Mac.

Comment: You will be looking for the same files. They can still be edited in a text editor.